# remove angular limitTo on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a list of posts and they are all different lengths so I'm cutting them off at the 500th character, but I want to show the remainder of the post on an `ng-click`. It seems like there might be some "angular way" to do this but I have not found it through google.

```
<ul id = "postsList">
  <li ng-repeat="post in Posts" >
    <p>{{ post.messageBody | limitTo:500 }}</p>
    <button ng-click = "undoLimitTo()">View</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would write it like:

set editable value for limit and give `Posts` length

```
<ul id = "postsList">
  <li ng-repeat="post in Posts" ng-init="limit= 500">
    <p>{{ post.messageBody | limitTo:limit }}</p>
    <button ng-click = "limit = Posts.length">View</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works too. Needed to add posts.messageBody.length though. Not sure what method I'll use yet.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<ul id = "postsList" ng-init="limit = 500">
  <li ng-repeat="post in Posts" >
    <p>{{ post.messageBody | limitTo:limit }}</p>
    <button ng-click = "limit = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER">View</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT

This is bullshit. It will change the limit for all posts.

You could in your controller add a `limit` property to the `Posts`. And then:

```
<ul id = "postsList">
  <li ng-repeat="post in Posts" >
    <p>{{ post.messageBody | limitTo:post.limit }}</p>
    <button ng-click = "post.limit = post.messageBody.length">View</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would add to controller: `$scope.Number = Number;` Angular doesnt know what is Number

Comment: Thanks guys. These suggestions have solved my issue. Will mark answered when the time window expires.

Comment: @phylax http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1297/    You need to bind `Number` with controller, no way :)

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a fiddle for you that does what I think you are after. The key is to keep track of the `listLimit` inside a controller, which changes upon clicking on the **more/less** text.

```js
var module = angular.module("MyModule", []);
module.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    // create the dummy list items
    $scope.list = [];
    for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
     $scope.list.push({
       value: i
      });
    }
    
    // set the initial item length
    $scope.totalItems = 5;
    
    // more/less clicked on
    $scope.more = function(){
     if($scope.totalItems === 5){
       $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
      }else{
       $scope.totalItems = 5;
      }     
    }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyModule" ng-controller="MyController">  
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="item in list | limitTo:totalItems">
      This is item {{$index}}           
     </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button" ng-click="more()">{{totalItems === 5 ? 'more' : 'less'}}</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

extremely simple version:

in controller:

```
$scope.limit = 3;

$scope.setLimit = function (number) {

    $scope.limit = number;

}
```

in HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:limit">

  <div ng-show="ng-show="items.length > limit && $index == 0">

    <span ng-click="setLimit (items.length)">show all</span>

  </div>

  <div>{item.yourexpression}}</div>

<div>
```

now it will only show the div if there are more items as the limit and it will show it only above the first item, we send the length of the ng-repeat to the controller and update the limit. Done!